# Java program to find the index of item entered by the user using method

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

How do I make a Java program that finds the index of any category entered by the user.

the method `Find()` receives the array and return the index of that specific category .The method should search in the array and print the index of the category if exists or “Not found" if not.

I wrote this code but I don't know how methods work exactly. I keep getting errors and I don't know how to fix them.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] cat = new String[5];
        cat[0] = "Design";
        cat[1] = "Biology";
        cat[2] = "Business";
        cat[3] = "Health";
        cat[4] = "History";

        System.out.print("Enter Category: ");
        String e = in.nextLine();
        new Example().Find();
        System.out.print("The index of " + cat[i] + " is: " + index);
    }

    public int Find() {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < cat.length; i++) {
            if (cat[i].equals(e)) {
                index = i;
                return index;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass `cat` and `e` as parameters to `Find()`. The function needs to change to `public int Find(String [] cat, String e) {...}`

Comment: Method find should have a default return in case it doesn't reach the if statement inside the for loop.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Java coding conventions usually state that classes start with upper case letters, but variables and method names start with lower case letters.

Comment: Consider making the find() method static so you don't have to instantiate Example to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.  Here is one way to do it with comments explaining things.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

// The way you initialzied your array is fine but you 
// could do the same thing like this which most times is easier.

// String[] cat =  { "Design", "Biology", "Business", "Health", "History" };

String[] cat = new String[5];
cat[0] = "Design";
cat[1] = "Biology";
cat[2] = "Business";
cat[3] = "Health";
cat[4] = "History";
```

```
System.out.print("Enter Category: ");
String e = in.nextLine();
```

You need to pass the category string and the array to the find method. The method returns the index of the string in the array.

```
int index = new Example().find(e, cat);
```

Now verify the index is valid. A `-1` means not found. Any other values should provide the location in the array.

```
if (index < 0) {
    System.out.println(e + " not found!");
}
else {
```

Now use the index to print out the value

```
    System.out.print("The index of " + cat[index] + " is: " + index);
}
```

This method was find except for passing the string and the array to the find method. And returning `i` is sufficient for the `index`. And by convention, method names start with lower case letters.

```
public int find(String str, String[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].equals(str)) {
           return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Note: within the `find` method, you don't need `index` at all. Just `return i`.

Comment: Nice catch!  Didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed a few thing. Looks like you need to read up on scope https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/:

1. Need to pass in e to find since you have it local to main
2. Need to set index variable in main.
3. Index you are returning is 0 based so not sure if you want that. My answer assumes you don't.
4. Need to pass in cat array

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] cat = new String[5];
        cat[0] = "Design";
        cat[1] = "Biology";
        cat[2] = "Business";
        cat[3] = "Health";
        cat[4] = "History";

        System.out.print("Enter Category: ");
        String e = in.nextLine();
        int index = Find(e);
        System.out.print("The index of " + cat[i] + " is: " + index);
    }

    public int Find(String e, String [] cat) {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < cat.length; i++) {
            if (cat[i].equals(e)) {
                return i+1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```